# Extract value of excel cell using PowerShell where contains

Tags: excel, powershell

How would I go about extracting an excel value via PS where a column value equals a string of text, for example 'Yes'. Example, if the string of 'Yes' is found in column M then output the value of column B for that row. I don't need the entire row values, just the one cell value which would be in column B for that row

Comment: Alright, sounds like you know exactly where you want to go! So, what is the question? How to open Excel programmatically? How to make string comparisons in PowerShell? How to reference another cell on the same row?

Comment: I am good with opening excel. Where I struggle with is programmatically pulling out the values of an excel cell where a string is contained. So if value of 'yes' is found in column 'M' then give me the value of column B2 for that row where yes is contained in column M